# Phusion Passenger set Environment for subdomain using same document root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, passenger, vhosts

I have a subdomain "staging.website.com" and "website.com" which I want to use the same app for but in different environment modes "closed" and "staging".

I have the following vHosts set up in Apache:

```
<VirtualHost 46.17.91.215:80>
  ServerName staging.website.com
  RackEnv staging 
  # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
  DocumentRoot /home/website/public_html/public   
  <Directory /home/website/public_html/public>
     # This relaxes Apache security settings.
     AllowOverride all
     # MultiViews must be turned off.
     Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 46.17.91.215:80>
  ServerName website.com
  ServerAlias www.website.com
  # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
  DocumentRoot /home/website/public_html/public
  RackEnv closed    
  <Directory /home/website/public_html/public>
     # This relaxes Apache security settings.
     AllowOverride all
     # MultiViews must be turned off.
     Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

*Obviously I have disguised my actual domain with "website.com".

Regardless of the different `RackEnv` set in the vhosts, they both use the same environment when accessed. I guess this is due to the same document root, but it must be achievable.

I have also tried with `RailsEnv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference, I found the answer here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/phusion-passenger/IKULD5QeLDw

```
Phusion Passenger identifies your application by its path. It
recognizes demo.example.com and example.com as the same app, so the
used RailsEnv will be whichever gets started first.

You can solve this issue by pointing both domains to different paths.
These paths may even be symlinks; Phusion Passenger doesn't resolve
them. So you can create a symlink /var/www/apps/myapp-demo, which
points to /var/www/apps/myapp, and point demo.example.com's
DocumentRoot to /var/www/apps/myapp-demo/public.
```

Answer (score 2):

Although undocumented right now, you can use the directive `PassengerAppGroupName` [since Passenger 3](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/543#issuecomment-44509473).

The config would be (note the different names for every VirtualHost block):

```
<VirtualHost 46.17.91.215:80>
  ServerName staging.website.com
  PassengerAppGroupName website-staging
  RackEnv staging 
  # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
  DocumentRoot /home/website/public_html/public   
  <Directory /home/website/public_html/public>
     # This relaxes Apache security settings.
     AllowOverride all
     # MultiViews must be turned off.
     Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 46.17.91.215:80>
  ServerName website.com
  PassengerAppGroupName website-closed
  ServerAlias www.website.com
  # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
  DocumentRoot /home/website/public_html/public
  RackEnv closed    
  <Directory /home/website/public_html/public>
     # This relaxes Apache security settings.
     AllowOverride all
     # MultiViews must be turned off.
     Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here you can find the [work-in-progress documentation](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/blob/f5c37d07ceda0be98710c102d7b1f1ba51a7f39e/doc/Users%20guide%20Apache.txt#L649) (not published in their website yet).